# Android Development: Using setText with SpannableString with Lots of Spans Slow, Workaround?

Tags: java, android, syntax-highlighting, android-edittext, spannablestring

I've made a little syntax highlighter for my app.

It performs the regular expressions and applies the ForegroundColorSpans to a copy of the EditText's contect - all in a thread. Once all this is done, the setText() method gets called and replaces the EditText's context with the now-styled copy.

Problem is, the setText() method causes the UI to freeze. In a test I did with a 2,000 line file it took 30 seconds to apply the styled text!

Aside from recommending users that the syntax highlighting shouldn't be used with big files and automatically turning it off if they are opening a big file, what can I do to speed the syntax highlighting up? Apart from reducing and making the regular expressions more efficient.

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've never used Traceview before. Basically I've timed it and it took 30 seconds to apply a styled String from a 2,000 line file to the EditText.

Comment: Then try Traceview, to give you an idea of what, specifically, under the covers, is giving you your grief. It might give you some ideas for solving your problem.

Comment: I tried to start it following what the docs said but got this:

alex@alexs-laptop:~$ traceview
    Usage: java com.android.traceview.MainWindow [-r] trace
  -r   regression only

Comment: I haven't used standalone `traceview` much. I've been using the Traceview that is available as part of the ADT plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: Ah I see. Well for some reason I don't have traceview in the list of Android views, but I have the rest like Threads, Logcat, View Hierarcy etc.

Comment: It should show up in the Debug perspective after you run a trace from within the DDMS perspective in Eclipse.

Comment: If you have used DroidEdit then I would suggest a doable trick: don't setText and syntax highlight the whole file! Keep track of the number of VISIBLE lines (computable from all the view metrics and text size) and invoke setText(content from start of first visible line to end of last visible line) when any sort of scrolling|movement occurs. You also need to use removeSpans() to keep the spans count low. If you also intent to allow user to edit the text, there will be another torrent of challenges.

Comment: I have the same issue in my app. I used traceview in the past, but it wouldn't record any android SDK classes, only my own, which is ofcourse useless. Did you find a solution? I will look into the partial highlighting, but I think that's a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a WebView or alternatively try to develop some functionality so that only the text visible to the user is styled.